# How does HIPAA apply to foreign entities?

Tags: united-states, medical

Since HIPAA is a U.S. law, my guess is that it only protects U.S. citizens or residents, but is there any part of the law that explicitly limits its protections to such persons? More practically, if a U.S. citizen consults with a doctor in England, is that doctor required to comply with HIPAA?

Comment: No, but if an English tourist consults a US doctor, that doctor is still bound by HIPAA, as I understand it.

Comment: by "consults with a doctor in England" do you mean the patient is in England and is being consulted "physically" by a doctor there? Or are you thinking about tele-medicine where the patient is in the US and the doctor is in England?

Answer (score 4):

### HIPAA applies to *covered entities*

Which, broadly speaking are entities that provide health care in the USA regardless of where they might be based.

The nationality of the patient is irrelevant.